# Asp.Net MVC DropDownListFor : how can the value be the whole object

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I need on one view to only choose between several element in a list. Element of my list are complex type.

I receive in the viewBag the list of all elements I can choose.

I tried several things without success, the most approaching thing of what I want is this:

```
@{SelectList list = new SelectList(ViewBag.Entities, Model);}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, list);
```

Have you an idea about how to use this?

**EDIT:**
Tried this too:

> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, new SelectList(ViewBag.Entities, "",
>   "Name"));

**EDIT2:** also tried to change my model, having a "int" as id, representing the current id of entity

> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, new SelectList(ViewBag.Entities, "Id",
>   "Name"));

Still have this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name
  Source=System.Web.Mvc
  ParamName=name
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor[TModel,TProperty](HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor[TModel,TProperty](HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList)
       at ASP._Page_Areas_Account_Views_Auth_EntityChooser_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Workspace\XYZ\Main\Code\AdManager\Areas\Account\Views\Auth\EntityChooser.cshtml:line 20
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What is the type of your model?

Comment: Depends of which try we are talking about, I tried to use my custom model, int, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**
I finally found a way to do it:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, new SelectList(
    Model.AvailableEntities, "Id", "Name"));
```

I had to put a property on my model which can store the value. It seems that the DropDownListFor doesn't really likes that I've this x=>x

Comment: Oh. If you'd told what your model on the view looked like, I could have told you that :)

Comment: but in the different tests, my model wasn't the same, in the first test, I was having directly one model of type "Entity", after that I was having a view model, with my object as property and now I've a view model with an id

Comment: And that's very important info, as you can see your solution required you to know about the property on the model :)

Answer (score 1):

The method you're calling, defines Model as the `SelectedValue`. You should give the names to use for `dataValueField` and `dataTextField`:

```
@{SelectList list = new SelectList(ViewBag.Entities, "Key", "Value");}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, list);
```

Given that `ViewBag.Entities` is a `Dictionary`. If it contains a list of your own objects, simply point to the properties you want to use, instead of Key and Value.

Comment: The problem, is that I do not have a "Key value to be set on the "x", I need the entire object of the list stored

Comment: Can you post what's inside ViewBag.Entities? The code for the complex type? Seems like what you're trying to do is not possible. You can only put a list of key/value pairs inside a dropdown list. Alternatively, you can serialize your object to JSON and put that in the value field. But that's a very bad idea IMHO!